# Creating contours based on values of ramp using QGIS

Tags: qgis, contour, color-ramp

When creating contour on a raster using QGIS, is it possible to create them based on values specified in a colour ramp ?

I only see the option "Interval between contour lines".

Comment: See this post for generating contours as specific values. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179001/generate-multiple-contour-lines-at-specific-elevations